# Azure AD Graph any $filter syntax

Tags: azure-ad-graph-api

I don't completely understand the `any` syntax from the example provided [here under the $filter documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-supported-queries-filters-and-paging-options#filter).  Nor can I find any more info about it.

> any is supported when querying multi-valued properties. For example: https://graph.windows.net/contoso.com/users?api-version=2013-11-08&$filter=userPrincipalName eq 'Mary@Contoso.com' or proxyAddresses/any(c:c eq 'smtp:Mary@Contoso.com')

What is the `c:c` part?  Seems like a lambda...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is the c:c part? Seems like lambda...

Yes, you are right. We could get more information about $filter Lambda Operators from this [tutorial](http://www.odata.org/getting-started/basic-tutorial/#lambda)

> OData defines two operators **any** and **all** that evaluate a Boolean expression on a collection. They can work on either collection properties or collection of entities.

According to the [UserEnity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#user-entity), we could know that proxyAddresses is **Collection(Edm.String)**. So `any(c:c eq 'smtp:Mary@Contoso.com')` equals to `User.proxyAddresses.Where(c=>c.equals("smtp:Mary@Contoso.com")`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are correct. `c` is a lambda variable here and `c eq 'smtp:Mary@Contoso.com'` is lambda expression.

`proxyAddresses/any(c:c eq 'smtp:Mary@Contoso.com')` will return collection of `proxyAddresses` for which the lambda expression returns true.

More examples and explanation can be found [here](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata02/os/complete/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.0-errata02-os-part2-url-conventions-complete.html#_Toc406398149).